# How to create calculated properties in data class with GSON implemented?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

Background: GSON, Kotlin, Retrofit

I am writing a restaurant app. In the home page, the user is able to load a list of restaurant brands. Each brand can have up to 3 cuisine types, the first one is non-null and the next two are nullable. Each cuisine type is within the CuisineType enum class.

What I would like to do is to create a joined string like this:
cuisineType1.title + cuisineType2?.title + cuisineType3?.title = combinedCuisines. This can make all cuisines shown within a textView in Chinese. In order to do this I created a helper class. In this helper class, if the CuisineType from Brand cannot map any of the enum members, it will display the raw name from the Brand JSON(incase of server error). I tried the three solutions commented out below and non of them work. Much help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
data class Brand(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name_en")
    val nameEN: String?,

    @SerializedName("cuisine_1")
    val cuisineType1: String,
    @SerializedName("cuisine_2")
    val cuisineType2: String?,
    @SerializedName("cuisine_3")
    val cuisineType3: String?,

    /*Solution 1(not working):
        val combinedCuisines = CombineCuisineHelper.combineCuisines(cuisineType1, cuisineType2, cuisineType3)
    ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class
    */

    /*Solution 2(not working):
        @Transient
        val combinedCuisines = CombineCuisineHelper.combineCuisines(cuisineType1, cuisineType2, cuisineType3)
    ***combinedCuisines = null after network call in fragment
    */
) {
    /* Solution 3(not working):
        val combinedCuisines: String
            get() = CombineCuisineHelper.combineCuisines(cuisineType1, cuisineType2, cuisineType3)
        ***problem with GSON, I can only map the @SerializedName from the Cuisine enum class and will only run the illegal argument solution from the CombineCuisineHelper. For example, get hong_kong_style from the JSON brand but it will not convert to HongKongStyle and map to its title.
    */
}

//It should be a long list but I shortened it.
enum class CuisineType {
    @SerializedName("chinese")
    Chinese,
    @SerializedName("hong_kong_style")
    HongKongStyle,
    @SerializedName("cantonese")
    Cantonese,

    val title: Double
    get() {
        return when (this) {
            Chinese       -> "中菜"
            HongKongStyle -> "港式"
            Cantonese     -> "粵式"
}

class CombineCuisineHelper {
    companion object {
        fun combineCuisines(cuisineSubtype1: String, cuisineSubtype2: String?, cuisineSubtype3: String?): String {
            val combinedSubtypes = ArrayList<String?>()
            combinedSubtypes += try {
                CuisineSubtype.valueOf(cuisineSubtype1).title
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                cuisineSubtype1
            }
            if (cuisineSubtype2 != null) {
                combinedSubtypes += try {
                    CuisineSubtype.valueOf(cuisineSubtype2).title
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    cuisineSubtype2
                }
            }
            if (cuisineSubtype3 != null) {
                combinedSubtypes += try {
                    CuisineSubtype.valueOf(cuisineSubtype3).title
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    cuisineSubtype3
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and second solutions are not good, because the data might not be ready at the initialization time. The third solution is the one we can continue on:

```
        val combinedCuisines: String
            get() = CombineCuisineHelper.combineCuisines(cuisineType1, cuisineType2, cuisineType3)
```

The `SerializedName`s are useless for enum constants and won't work for you as you are expecting. So the `valueOf` method for enum won't find a value for literals like `"hong_kong_style"` and will throw an exception.

You can create your own helper method in your enum class like this:

```
enum class CuisineType {
    Chinese,
    HongKongStyle,
    Cantonese;

    val title: String
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Chinese -> "中菜"
                HongKongStyle -> "港式"
                Cantonese -> "粵式"
            }
        }

    companion object {
        //Note this helper method which manually maps string values to enum constants:
        fun enumValue(title: String): CuisineType = when (title) {
            "chinese" -> Chinese
            "hong_kong_style" -> HongKongStyle
            "cantonese" -> Cantonese
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown cuisine type $title")
        }
    }
}
```

And then use this new method instead of the enum's own `valueOf` method:

```
            val combinedSubtypes = ArrayList<String?>()
            combinedSubtypes += try {
                CuisineType.enumValue(cuisineSubtype1).title
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                cuisineSubtype1
            }
            //continued...
```

Comment: I was reading the kotlin documentation and I was wondering whether the code can be improved with the Generic enum value access? ```enum class RGB { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> printAllValues() { print(enumValues<T>().joinToString { it.name })
}``` Thanks!